# Attachment match table attaching too many files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attachments, arcgis-10.6

I'm having a problem correctly generating a match file for a folder of pdfs. The pdfs all have numeric file names - 10.pdf, 58.pdf, 586.pdf, 587.pdf, etc. The feature class where the files are getting attached has a field, TxtSt, that contains the name of the pdfs without the .pdf extension - 10, 58, 586, 587, etc. Not every pdf will necessarily match with a value in TxtSt.

When I run the Generate Match Table tool, it creates the match table. The problem is that if the value of TxtSt is 58, the tool is also matching 586, 587, and so on. It's as if the match process uses a wildcard - 58*, for example - to match anything beginning with that value.

I don't know if this is an error on my part or in the tool, but this is puzzling me.

Comment: Are you running the tool with the default settings? Are you leaving the "in_file_filter" Parameter blank?

Comment: Yes, default settings, in_file_filter parameter blank.

Comment: I don't see an option for an exact match. Long shot: Try appending ".pdf" to the vals in yourTxtSt field, maybe then they will match up.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the match table with `copyrow` tool to another empty table with `object Id`, then use `delete identical` tool to retain the first repeated row. This will reduce your workload.